# JQuery UI Dialog dont update on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have this problem with my JQuery UI Modal window. Its used when i click a button, then it opens up and append contents to it trough an Ajax call to a php file. Works perfectly the first time i open it, but then when i click another button that should show different content, it still shows the old content in it, and i have to refresh the page for it to work.

This is my Dialog open event which is triggered by a switch, and the last part which appends data to my select box on creation.

```
$( "#attack" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    width:"400px",
    buttons: {

        Attack: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },

        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});



$("#users").selectmenu({
    create: function( event, ui ) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mapfunctions/FetchUsers.php",
            data: {RegionID: RegionID},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#users").append(data);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

The dialog looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhkUj.png
The HTML for it is a bit long, so i hope you dont need that dialog code, if so, let me know and i will add.

Its the Select menu which keeps the old data from the first ajax call.

I tried using Destroy and such on close, but then the dialog would simply never open again heh.

Thanks a lot people, hope this is enough for a clear understanding

Comment: can make a jsfiddle for that. and in attack why are you calling model close.

Comment: There will come some extra code in those 2 buttons, but thats not relavent for the issue i think?

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem with ajax and modal windows.. on clicking next button you have to reset the form and load it new.

for eg:

If you are using form with id "myForm" then on clicking another button reset the form like `$("#myForm").trigger('reset');` in jQuery. or any other way

Comment: I tried adding this to my cancel button:

http://i.imgur.com/cNem0xK.png

It didnt do anything thou :(

Comment: i need to see little code of you to understand what is happening!

Comment: There is a lot of code in this section, but i tried cleaning it up so its only the relevant pieces that is shown: http://i.imgur.com/wV7BnpJ.png 

Its the select menu, thats not updating contents, and the #Users is the ID of the selectmenu in my #Attack dialog.

Hope it makes sense